# How to change top panel color in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, colors

My top panel/dashboard/menubar is black. I want to change it to white. Tried compiz, gnome-shell.css on my current theme, system gnome-shell.css, dconf/gconf editor, and many other ways. I am not using dash to panel or dash to dock. I am on 20.04. How can I change the panel's color?

Comment: I have 20.04 with Budgie desktop.  I can make some changes to the transparency of my top panel by going to the "Budgie Desktop Settings" app.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and mention in details what you have done so far, especially regarding editing the `gnome-shell.css` file(s). That should work provided you have made the *correct* changes to the *correct* `css` file (which may not even be available by default) associated to your *current shell theme*.

Comment: I did do that, I had to enable the user shell theme extension in gnome tweaks. Thank you for trying to help though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use a GNOME extension called [**Dynamic Panel Transparency**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/). In the extension settings you can change the top bar color and text color to whatever you'd like.

Comment: This does not change the panel color in the additional monitor. How can we do this?

Comment: Is there a way to set this without needing to install a browser extension???

Comment: Yes, if you edit the gnome-shell.css file AND enable the user shell themes extension (preinstalled), it should work with no browser extension (asumming you use GNOME Tweaks) and both monitors

Answer (score 1):

Within the gnome-shell theme you can modify the section that contains:

```
#panel .panel-button
```

and add/modify the line that contains for example:

```
background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
```

if you want to modify the text color:

```
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
```